# Check DNS to see if Record Exists

Tags: windows, powershell, server, dns

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to do the following:

1. Open up my CSV file.  Column A has the hostname of a server.  Column B has the IP Address
2. I then want to see if the hostname exists in DNS.  I do a check on the first hostname and if the host exists, proceed to the next hostname.  If it doesn't, add the new A-Record into DNS with hostname and ip.

My issue is that when it does a check to see if the record exists in DNS, it says that the record does not exist and then tries to create it when in fact it does exist in DNS.
This is my script:

```
# Declare Variables. These variables are different in each domain
$ZoneName = "domain.com"
$DNSServer = "domain1.domain.com"
$ExistsInDNS = "C:\myScripts\DNSScavenging\RestoreDNSRecords\ExistsInDNS.txt"
$RestoredToDNS = "C:\myScripts\DNSScavenging\RestoreDNSRecords\RestoredToDNS.txt"

$DNSRecords = Import-Csv -path "C:\myScripts\DNSScavenging\RestoreDNSRecords\dnsrestoretest.csv" -Header "Server","IP"  

foreach ($DNSRecord in $DNSRecords){

    # Check DNS to see if the Server and IP exists
    write-host "Checking to see if $($DNSRecord.Server) exists in DNS"
    $DNSCheck = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($DNSRecord.Server)                   
    if ($($DNSCheck.HostName) -contains $($DNSRecord.Server)) {         
        write-host "$($DNSRecord.Server) $($DNSRecord.IP) exists in DNS" -ForegroundColor "Green" 
        write-output "$($DNSRecord.Server) $($DNSRecord.IP)" | out-file $ExistsInDNS -Append
    } else { 
        write-host "$($DNSRecord.Server) $($DNSRecord.IP) does not exist in DNS.  Restoring $($DNSRecord.Server) $($DNSRecord.IP) in DNS" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
        write-output "$($DNSRecord.Server) $($DNSRecord.IP)"  | out-file $RestoredToDNS -Append
        # Add record into DNS   
        Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneName "$ZoneName" -Name $DNSRecord.Server -AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address $DNSRecord.IP
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use :

`Resolve-DnsName -Name "DNSEntry" -Server "yourserver"`

This way you can check your target dns server directly and you just need to check if it returns true.

Comment: That worked better!  I used that cmdlet and changed the logic a little bit to fit that

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this, I'll save you a couple hours of mucking around. Format a .csv like this below, including the header but don't use the fqdn in this case, just hostname.

```
name,ip
testnameexample,192.168.1.1
```

and use this code:

```
#Declare Variables. These variables are different in each domain
$ZoneName = "yourdomain.com"
#$DNSServer = "yourdnsserver.yourdomain.com"
$ExistsInDNS = "C:\temp\ExistsInDNS.txt"
$RestoredToDNS = "C:\temp\AddedToDNS.txt"

$DNSRecords = Import-Csv -path "C:\temp\IP_LIST.csv" -Header "name","ip"  

foreach ($DNSRecord in $DNSRecords){

    # Check DNS to see if the Server and IP exists
    write-host "Checking to see if $($DNSRecord.name) exists in DNS"          
    $DNSCheck = $(resolve-DnsName -name "$($DNSRecord.name).$ZoneName" -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | select-object Name)
    write-host "DNS Lookup Result [blank if not found]: $($DNSCheck.Name)"
    if ($($DNSCheck.Name) -match $($DNSRecord.name)) {         
        write-host "$($DNSRecord.name) $($DNSRecord.ip) exists in DNS, Skipping.." -ForegroundColor "Green" 
        write-output "$($DNSRecord.name) $($DNSRecord.ip)" | out-file $ExistsInDNS -Append
    } else { 
        write-host "$($DNSRecord.name) $($DNSRecord.ip) does not exist in DNS.  Adding $($DNSRecord.name) $($DNSRecord.ip) in DNS" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
        write-output "$($DNSRecord.name) $($DNSRecord.ip)"  | out-file $RestoredToDNS -Append
        # Add record into DNS   
        #Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneName "$ZoneName" -Name $($DNSRecord.name) -AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address $($DNSRecord.ip)
        Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -ZoneName "$ZoneName" -Name $($DNSRecord.name) -AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address $($DNSRecord.ip)
    }
}
```